# Summarize rows with continued date range

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle19c

**Oracle 19c version**

Not sure if it is possible to write a query to achieve what I am asking but didn't want to rule out without checking with the pros here!

I tried to create this table & data in dbfiddle & sqlfiddle but getting errors.  So here are the scripts.

```
create table xxtest (
  person_number   number,
  full_name       varchar2(100),
  grade           varchar2(10),
  st_date         date,
  end_date        date
);

insert into xxtest values (1,'John Doe','E02',to_date('2023-01-01','YYYY-MM-DD'),to_date('2023-01-23','YYYY-MM-DD'));
insert into xxtest values (1,'John Doe','E02',to_date('2023-01-30','YYYY-MM-DD'),to_date('2023-02-28','YYYY-MM-DD'));
insert into xxtest values (1,'John Doe','E02',to_date('2023-03-01','YYYY-MM-DD'),to_date('2023-03-12','YYYY-MM-DD'));
insert into xxtest values (1,'John Doe','E02',to_date('2023-03-15','YYYY-MM-DD'),to_date('2023-03-31','YYYY-MM-DD'));
insert into xxtest values (1,'John Doe','E02',to_date('2023-04-01','YYYY-MM-DD'),to_date('2023-12-31','YYYY-MM-DD'));
insert into xxtest values (1,'John Doe','N01',to_date('2023-01-24','YYYY-MM-DD'),to_date('2023-01-29','YYYY-MM-DD'));

select a.*, a.end_date-a.st_date days
from xxtest a;
```

So the data looks like this:

[image]

Expected output is shown below.  By person, name & grade, if there is no break in the dates, then those rows should be summarized and have the sum of the days between the st_date & end_date.

I have color coded the above rows and shown as rolled up in below image.

[image]

As always, truly appreciate your help!

Comment: FYI - when I tried to create scripts, dbfiddle.uk is giving below errors
`ORA-00922: missing or invalid option`
`ORA-00911: invalid character`

And sqlfiddle.com is stuck at Building Schema and then getting below error
`Oops! Something went wrong. Try it again and if this keeps happening, email admin@sqlfiddle.com about it.`

Comment: You can reproduce the case by using [the link](https://dbfiddle.uk/TLTwtKmU). **Hint** : **lag/lead** along with **gaps-and-islands** . Good night.

Comment: @maskeerr `match_recognize` is the best option for that, considering you are on 19c

Comment: https://dbfiddle.uk/ov7LzObI

Comment: Thank you all for the help.  So I need a BEGIN..END block for the insert statements.  

Not sure though what is wrong with SQL Fiddle.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```sql
select *
  from xxtest a
match_recognize(
  partition by person_number,full_name,grade
  order by st_date
  MEASURES 
     first(st_date) as dt_start,
     last(end_date) as dt_end,
     sum(end_date-st_date) as days
  PATTERN (st nxt*) 
  DEFINE 
    nxt AS st_date = prev(end_date)+1
);
```

DBFiddle: https://dbfiddle.uk/ov7LzObI

```
PERSON_NUMBER   FULL_NAME   GRADE   DT_START    DT_END      DAYS
1               John Doe    E02     01-JAN-23   23-JAN-23   22
1               John Doe    E02     30-JAN-23   12-MAR-23   40
1               John Doe    E02     15-MAR-23   31-DEC-23   290
1               John Doe    N01     24-JAN-23   29-JAN-23   5
```

Comment: Thank you so much _/\_  That works like a charm.  Now to understand how match_recognize works! :-)